# Are default constructor and default initialization related?

Tags: c++, initialization

I know about default constructor but are they related to default initialization?
Also i would like to more about default initialization.

Also cppreference says,"default initialization is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed with no initializer "  but initialization performed with not initializer is calling of default constructor.Can anyone also explain this

Comment: Unrelated. "default constructor" means simply it can be called with no arguments.

Comment: where can i find more about default initialization?

Comment: Try cppreference.com or google.com. Or the search box on this site.

Comment: @M.M cppreference says,"default initialization is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed with no initializer " but initialization performed with not initializer is calling of default constructor. Can you explain this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of basic research

Answer (score 0):

They are related only in the sense that default initialization on a class type will result in calling a default constructor if that constructor is non-trivial.